# Python3 f string alternative in Python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have this python3 code ( formatted with `f` string ):

```
folder = r"C:\Users\test"

for _,g in df.groupby(df['ID'].notna().cumsum()):
    g.iloc[:,1:].dropna(how='all').to_csv(f"{folder}\\{g.iloc[0,0]}.txt",index=False)
```

i am trying to format this in python2.7:

mycode in python2.7 :

```
folder = r"C:\Users\test"

for _,g in df.groupby(df['ID'].notna().cumsum()):
    g.iloc[:,1:].dropna(how='all').to_csv("{}".format(folder+\\(g.iloc[0,0])+str(".txt")),index=False)
```

i have got this error:

[image]

What i am doing wrong? Thanks for your attention and help.

Comment: Try this, ``"{folder}\\{file}.txt".format(folder=folder, file=g.iloc[0,0])``

Comment: ``\\`` is not an operator; it's part of the string literal.

Comment: you have to use \\ inside string `"{}\\{}.txt".format(folder, g.iloc[0,0])`

Comment: BTW: see page https://pyformat.info/

Comment: @sushant, thank you i tried your suggestion but  i got error 'AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'notna'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move variables from `{ }` to `format()` and keep rest in string

```
"{}\\{}.txt".format(folder, g.iloc[0,0])
```

instead of

```
f"{folder}\\{g.iloc[0,0]}.txt"
```

You can learn more on https://pyformat.info/

Comment: thank you for your response. but i have got an error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'notna'`

Comment: is it becuase of python2? the code is working fine in python3.

Comment: @Ram try `notnull()` inplace of `notna()` seems like the pandas version is  less than `0.22` ..?

Comment: if you have new error then you should create new question on new page - it seems this error has nothing to do with f-string.

Comment: @anky ihave got the error with your suggestion  `***keyword argument reapeted`

Comment: @ furas, thank you if needed i will make a new question. i thought its a small issue but seems to be complex.

Comment: @furas, and to anky i followed both your advise and its now working in python2 without any problems. Thanks once more to both of you.

Comment: you guys are really super

Answer (score 0):

The double slash here: put it in quotes:

```
folder+'\\'+(g.iloc[0,0])+str(".txt")),index=False
```

Though I prefer to use `os.sep` instead of `\\`